# Why does iodine stay in the aqueous layer of a hexane/salt water mixture?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

All the procedures take place in test tubes. There is also stirring in each case.

$\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{I2}$ are simultaneously added to a water solution. Then we add hexane. There is no reaction between the $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{I2}$. The water is colored yellow quite intensely, but the hexane stays colorless and transparent. Why the organic phase created is not colored, in spite the fact that we have $\ce{I2}$ in the solution?

A similar experiment, with a water solution of only $\ce{I2}$ added to hexane, showed, after a sudden stirring, that the hexane phase was indeed colored purple, as expected, and the water phase yellow. The colors were not as intense as previously.

Another experiment of $\ce{NaI}$ and $\ce{Cl2}$ in water solution added to hexane had as a result the coloring of the hexane phase to purple. Water phase was yellow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124959/discussion-on-question-by-well-kapos-why-does-iodine-stay-in-the-aqueous-layer-o).

Comment: Separating iodine from aqueous NaCl is a standard teaching experiment. That is how people would isolate iodine from brines/ or seawater after oxidizing iodide ions. 

I am unsure if your experiment has some information missing or if it needs to be repeated. Sometimes overthinking causes more problems.

Comment: People have studied the interactions of molecular iodine and seawater. It takes several days to observe disproportionation or chemical reduction. It is very likely there is an experimental mistake in your observation.